# How can I override CSS id?

Tags: html, css

I have the following css:

```css
#app-info           { float: left; margin: 10px 10px; }
#app-info ul        { list-style-type:none; display:block; }
#app-info ul li     { padding:2px 0; }

#content            { width:650px; float:left;  }
#content ul         { padding-left: 40px; padding-bottom: 15px; }
#content ul li      { padding:5px 0; }
```

Then I have the code:

```
<div id="content">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>       

    <div id="app-info">
        <ul>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue i'm having is that the inner list is being formatted by the `content` id, however I don't want this. I only want the `app-info` class to format it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Those are IDs, not classes. It's important that you don't get the two mixed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Child Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) `'>'` instead of [Descendant Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) `' '`.

```css
#content            { width:650px; float:left;  }
#content > ul       { padding-left: 40px; padding-bottom: 15px; }
#content > ul li    { padding:5px 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
#content            { width:650px; float:left;  }
#content > ul         { padding-left: 40px; padding-bottom: 15px; }
#content > ul li      { padding:5px 0; }
```